# Issues when storing files in UWP app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I'm currently working on an UWP XAML/C# app and I need to store data to my local folder. When executing the Code below I get this error: 'IAsyncAction' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and the best extension method overload 'AwaitExtensions.GetAwaiter(Task)' requires a receiver of type 'Task'.

```
StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("userInformation.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, responseContent.ToString()));
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nArVO.png)

Update: full method

```
private async void Login()
    {
        StorageFile file = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("userInformation.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "sample txt");
    }
```

Comment: I tested your code, it works fine by my side, how did you get the localfolder?  Can you please create a new empty UWP project and test this code again?

Comment: When doing this, I get the error: The type 'IAsyncOperation' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.

Comment: If creating a new empty project can't help this problem, then I think the problem is possible with your VS tool, please try to reinstall VS.

Comment: Well, I feared that...

Comment: Yeah, I can understand...but since we don't have any better idea now, it might be a way to solve your problem.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, reinstalling didn't solve the problem neither.

Answer (score 0):

This code works without any problem:

```
 StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("userInformation.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
 await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "some text");
```

As I see there is one extra bracket in your code. Second line should be:

```
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, responseContent.ToString());
```

Comment: I don't know, what's the problem... But for me, this won't work

Comment: have you tried to replace responseContent.ToString() with some text. write in second line await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "some text");

Comment: And same exception? Does your method is async? Publish whole method, plz.